# how to set decimal value of (2) js datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, decimal

Im trying to set my decimal numbers to two(2) but I cannot succeed. Any help would be appreciated. I am calculating the average number per column view and average total of all the column. The problem I'm facing is, that I have up to 14 position after the decimal point and I would like to reduce this to (2) only. I am working with Datatables and there is indicated the use of .toFixed(2). I tried but can not work it out. please see below and the fiddle

I provided a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwf79jok/9/) for my situation.

Thank you in advance

```
$('#dtcuidadhrs').DataTable({
responsive: true,
"footerCallback": function(tfoot, data, start, end, display) {
    var api = this.api();

    for (var i = 0; i < api.columns().count(); i++) {

        var columnDataTotal = api
            .column(i)
            .data();
        var theColumnTotal = columnDataTotal
            .reduce(function(a, b) {
                if (isNaN(a)) {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    a = parseFloat(a);
                }
                if (isNaN(b)) {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    b = parseFloat(b);
                }
                return (a + b).toFixed(2);
            }, 0);

        var columnData = api
           .column( i, { page: 'current'} )
           .data()
        var theColumnPage = columnData
            .reduce(function(a, b) {
                if (isNaN(a)) {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    a = parseFloat(a);
                }
                if (isNaN(b)) {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    b = parseFloat(b);
                }
                return (a + b).toFixed(2);
            }, 0);

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 0 ).footer() ).html('Avarage');
        $(api.column(i).footer()).html(
            theColumnPage / columnData.count() + ' ('+ theColumnTotal / columnDataTotal.count() +' Total)'
        );
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JS fiddle, you are running a reduce to sum the average of each column using toFixed.

When doing calculations, it's best to only round on the very final number (otherwise loss of precision is a serious concern).
Try the following: I would refactor a bit, but you get the idea

```
// Update footer
            $( api.column( 0 ).footer() ).html('Avarage');
            $(api.column(i).footer()).html(
                theColumnPage / columnData.count() + ' ('+ parseFloat(theColumnTotal / columnDataTotal.count()).toFixed(2) +' Total)'
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much Neal. what means I have to take out the toFixed in the average calculation and use only in the final.

Comment: No problem Pascal.
The jest of it is, inside of your Reduce functions where you call   return (a + b).toFixed(2);
Replace it with return a+b. 

Then only round where I showed you (the absolute final step) :). This will make sure your numbers are a lot more accurate. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic